# Spring-Boot Database integration testing against oracle DB

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, integration-testing

I am trying to test my application against an Oracle 11g DB using spring-boot and JPA. However I keep getting the following errors.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @ConditionalOnMissingBean did not specify a bean using type, name or annotation and the attempt to deduce the bean's type failed
```

and

```
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanTypeDeductionException: Failed to deduce bean type for org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.jta.NarayanaJtaConfiguration.narayanaProperties
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/arjuna/ats/jbossatx/jta/RecoveryManagerService
```

I created a `applications-test.properties` under resources and then created my tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = RequestApplication.class )
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:applications-test.properties")
public class ApplicantImplTest {


    private Applicant applicant;

    @Autowired
    public void setApplicant(Applicant applicant){
        this.applicant = applicant;
    }

    @Before
    @Sql({"applicant.sql"})
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Before ran");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("tear down ran");
    }

    @Test
    @Sql({"applicant.sql"})
    public void findbySSN() throws Exception {
        TApplicant tApplicant;

        tApplicant = applicant.findbySSN("000000008");

        assertNotNull(tApplicant.getIndSsn());
        assertEquals(Optional.of("N"), tApplicant.getAsvabScrTypCd());
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteByssn() throws Exception {
        TApplicant tApplicant;

        tApplicant = applicant.findbySSN("000000008");

        if (tApplicant != null){
            applicant.deleteByssn("000000008");
        }

        assertEquals(null,applicant.findbySSN("000000008"));
    }

    @Test
    public void createApplicant() throws Exception {

        TApplicant createdApplicant = new TApplicant();

        createdApplicant.setIndSsn("000001111");
        createdApplicant.setBirthDt(new Date(19900202));
        createdApplicant.setIndivName("Drew");

        applicant.createApplicant(createdApplicant);

        TApplicant tApplicant;

        tApplicant = applicant.findbySSN("000001111");

        assertEquals("000001111",tApplicant.getIndSsn());
        assertEquals(new Date(19900202),tApplicant.getBirthDt());
        assertEquals("Drew",tApplicant.getIndivName());

    }

    @Test
    public void updateApplicant() throws Exception {

        TApplicant tApplicant;

        tApplicant = applicant.findbySSN("000000008");

        if (tApplicant != null){

            assertEquals("000000008",tApplicant.getIndSsn());
            tApplicant.setIndSsn("000000009");
            applicant.updateApplicant(tApplicant);
            assertEquals("000000009",tApplicant.getIndSsn());
        }

    }

}
```

Here is a small snippet of my class I am testing:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class ApplicantImpl implements Applicant {

    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ApplicantImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private ApplicantRepo applicantRepo;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public TApplicant findbySSN(String ssn) throws ServletException {
        TApplicant applicant = new TApplicant();

        if (ssn != null){
            applicant = applicantRepo.findOne(ssn);
        }else{
            throw new ServletException("Applicant does not exist or wrong SSN was entered.");
        }

        return applicant;
    }
```

Here is my Repo

```
public interface ApplicantRepo extends CrudRepository<TApplicant, String> {

}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

------------- FULL ERROR STACKTRACE--------------------------

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.jta.NarayanaJtaConfiguration.narayanaProperties
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:336)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:246)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:111)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @ConditionalOnMissingBean did not specify a bean using type, name or annotation and the attempt to deduce the bean's type failed
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.validate(OnBeanCondition.java:310)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:300)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanTypeDeductionException: Failed to deduce bean type for org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.jta.NarayanaJtaConfiguration.narayanaProperties
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:373)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanType(OnBeanCondition.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:294)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/arjuna/ats/jbossatx/jta/RecoveryManagerService
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:612)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:360)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.RecoveryManagerService
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 56 more


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.jta.NarayanaJtaConfiguration.narayanaProperties
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:336)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:246)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:111)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @ConditionalOnMissingBean did not specify a bean using type, name or annotation and the attempt to deduce the bean's type failed
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.validate(OnBeanCondition.java:310)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:300)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanTypeDeductionException: Failed to deduce bean type for org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.jta.NarayanaJtaConfiguration.narayanaProperties
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:373)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanType(OnBeanCondition.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:294)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/arjuna/ats/jbossatx/jta/RecoveryManagerService
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:612)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:360)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.RecoveryManagerService
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 56 more
```

------`application.properties`-------

```
#Oracle database setup
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@999.999.999.999:1521:d9rty
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.profiles.active=oracle

#JPA setup
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

spring.datasource.max-active=5

server.port = 4000
```

-------------------------UPDATE 2-------------------------------

I added :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jta-narayana</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

and it fixed the error: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/arjuna/ats/jbossatx/jta/RecoveryManagerService`

However now it is saying:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applications.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

Since I created a `applicions-test.properties` too which has the same configuration as `application.properties` I tried that one too via:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = RequestApplication.class )
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:applications-test.properties")
```

which gives me an error saying `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: XADataSource`

What I am trying to figure out why `@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:applications.properties")` is saying:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applications.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I think once that is solved I my test will be able to run. Both files are location under `src-> main -> resources -> application.properties` and `src-> main -> resources -> application-test.properties`

---------------------------UPDATE 3----------------------------

Had a typo `appliations.properties` was suppose to be `application.properties`

However my new error is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: XADataSource
    at org.springframework.boot.jta.narayana.NarayanaDataSourceBean.getConnection(NarayanaDataSourceBean.java:58) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:254) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:228) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
```

So I click on NarayanaDataSourceBean.java and see `XADataSource` symbol cannot be resolved.

```
public class NarayanaDataSourceBean implements DataSource {

    private final XADataSource xaDataSource;

    /**
     * Create a new {@link NarayanaDataSourceBean} instance.
     * @param xaDataSource the XA DataSource
     */
    public NarayanaDataSourceBean(XADataSource xaDataSource) {
        Assert.notNull(xaDataSource, "XADataSource must not be null");
        this.xaDataSource = xaDataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(TransactionalDriver.XADataSource, this.xaDataSource);
        return ConnectionManager.create(null, properties);
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String username, String password)
            throws SQLException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(TransactionalDriver.XADataSource, this.xaDataSource);
        properties.put(TransactionalDriver.userName, username);
        properties.put(TransactionalDriver.password, password);
        return ConnectionManager.create(null, properties);
    }
```

What is confusing is I am using the embedded tomcat server and a Oracle 11G DB. Why am I having to use anything related to JBOSS.

Comment: Could you share minimal source code for testing this problem?

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace, please?

Comment: @Patrick please see update 1

Comment: @imagine I don't know what else to show you unless the `application.properties` would help. I posted the full stacktrace under `----Update 1----`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a XADataSource, this is for transaction management.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {


    @Value("${statdb.driverClassName}")
    private String statdbDriverClassName;

    @Value("${statdb.url}")
    private String statdbUrl;

    @Value("${statdb.id}")
    private String statdbId;

    @Value("${statdb.pw}")
    private String statdbPw;

    @Value("${statdb.validationQuery}")
    private String statdbValidationQuery;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSourceStatdb() {
        XADataSource dataSource = new XADataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(statdbDriverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(statdbUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(statdbId);
        dataSource.setPassword(statdbPw);
        dataSource.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1 FROM dual"); //for Oracle
        return dataSource;
    }
```

and

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jta-narayana</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

to your POM

Answer (score -1):

At a glance there is a no class found exception

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.RecoveryManagerService

As you don't put your `pom.xml` (or gradle) here, so assume you are [Using the Narayana transaction manager](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-jta.html#boot-features-jta-narayana), so please refer to the guide:

1. Make sure the `spring-boot-starter-jta-narayana` in your pom.xml
2. In your `ApplicantImplTest` test it used the `applications-test.properties` and you updated the `applications.properties`, so please check the Narayana configuration `spring.jta.narayana.properties` in your `application.properties`

But I'm not sure you really don't wanner to using distributed transaction, otherwise you need follow the above guide to setup the env, here is a good tutorial - [Configuring Spring and JTA without full Java EE](https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee/), but for test propose, maybe the standard local transaction will be more eaiser. [Ref](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)

Comment: 1) I do not have `spring-boot-starter-jta-narayana` in my pom. 
2) `applications-test.properties` has the same configuration as `applications.properties`, that was my mistake for posting `applications.properties`. Hope this works and I will post my pom shortly.

Comment: Please see update 2, thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: Maybe you should use `@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath*:applications.properties")`

Comment: Thank you for your efforts but `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [classpath*:applications.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist` did not work.

Comment: Sorry, should `application.properties`

Comment: Fixed the typo and got `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: XADataSource` same error I had when I used when I used `@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:applications-test.properties")` This is beyond frustrating.

Comment: `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: XADataSource
`

Comment: Maybe you really don't wanner to using distributed transaction, otherwise you need follow the above guide to setup the env, here is a good tutorial - [Configuring Spring and JTA without full Java EE](https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee/), but for test propose, maybe the standard local transaction will be more eaiser. Ref - http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

Comment: please see update 3 and I took out @Transcational for now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126650/discussion-between-drew1208-and-liping-huang).